# wp_enqueue_script stripping domain name from absolute url (google maps api) Thesis 2.1.4

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, rackspace-cloud, wordpress-thesis-theme

just trying to figure this one out... I have a plugin that is registering the google maps api url using wp_register_script and then calls it using wp_enqueue_script which all looks correct to me.  When the page renders though, the domain name has been stripped from the url so it is calling a relative path at that point and breaking the script... any ideas

worpress: 7.1
thesis: 2.1.4

```
// register the script
    wp_register_script( 'map_list-google-places', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places' . $languageString);

//Load google maps
    wp_enqueue_script( 'map_list-google-places');
```

in the HEAD

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/maps/api/js?sensor=true&#038;libraries=places&#038;ver=3.7.1'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here.  There is a plugin called Relative Root Plugin that is installed during my server's (Rackspace Cloud Sites) spin of the Wordpress site.

Simply Deactivate or Delete the plugin.  DONE.